# Splitting variable with json leads to Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, json, split, typeerror

I'm trying to split the content of a variable `pickerValue`, so that the end result only shows "eosptest2"

The console.log shows `pickerValue: i:0#.w|opmain\eosptest2;`

The problem is that I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` at the following line:

```
return json[0].id.split("\\")[1];
```

This is the function:

```
function getUserNameFromPeoplePicker(pickerValue, returnType) {

    if (checkNull(pickerValue) == "") {
        return "";
    }

    var json;

    try {
        json = JSON.parse(pickerValue);
    } catch (err) {
        return replaceSubstring(pickerValue.split("\\")[1], ";", "");
    } finally {
        switch (returnType) {
            case "label":
                console.log("json[0].label: " + json[0].label);
                return json[0].label;
                break;

            case "id":
                console.log("pickerValue: " + pickerValue);
                // console.log("Json id split: " + json[0].id.split("\\")[1]);
                return json[0].id.split("\\")[1];

            default:

                return replaceSubstring(pickerValue.split("\\")[1], ";", "");
                //return replaceSubstring(json[0].value.split("\\")[1], ";", "");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

To test it, I replaced the return statement with `return "eosptest2"` and it worked fine, but I don't know what exactly needs to be changed.

How can one fix this issue?

Comment: Can you log and include in the question the value inside `pickerValue`? Because it seems that your variable `json` is undefined.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Sorry, what should I make a console.log() of?

Comment: I would like to see what is inside `pickerValue` when you receive the console error about `json` being undefined.

Comment: `console.log(json);` says `undefined`

Comment: Why aren't you logging the error in the `catch()`? That's where it's going wrong I assume. The problem is when the `catch()` is run, that means `json` will remained undefined, and the two switch cases in your `finally` block will always throw an error.

Comment: How you want to fix it is up to you, but you'll need to either default `json` to some value, or just have the function return nothing when an error is caught.

Comment: @YannickK Logging the error in the catch yields the same result. I tried replacing the return statement `replaceSubstring(pickerValue.split("\\")[1], ";", "");` with `""`, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @PoliticsStudent here is the problem: when `pickerValue` is empty, JSON parse call fails, so your `json` variable remains undefined, and you can't call `[0]` on something that is undefined, so that line fails. The question is, what should be returned when `pickerValue` is undefined?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi `pickerValue` is always defined, but it probably takes some time to retrieve the value. But that's why I added `if (checkNull(pickerValue) == "") {
        return "";
    }`

Comment: What do you mean it takes some time? Do you mean you have asynchronous code that fetches the value of `pickerValue`?

Comment: And keep in mind that `JSON.parse("")` also fails.

Comment: I can't really make it much more clear than in my answer, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running your switch cases under the assumption that the `json` variable is always defined, but if the `catch()` block ran, that means that your `json` variable will be undefined:

```js
function example(value) {
    var json;

    try {
        json = JSON.parse(value);
    } catch (err) {
        // couldn't parse the value, so you catch an error
        console.error(err);

        return "catch";
    } finally {
        // an error got caught, this block runs regardless, and now json is undefined
        console.log(`json variable: ${json}`);
    }
}

const result = example(";");
console.log(result);
```

What you're also assuming is that if you have a return statement in the `catch()` block, this will stop the `finally` block from executing, but that's not true. The `finally` block will execute its code, and only then will it return some statement.

Also note that if you have a return statement in both the `catch` and `finally` block, the `finally` return statement will take priority over the other:

```js
function example(value) {
    var json;

    try {
        json = JSON.parse(value);
    } catch (err) {
        // couldn't parse the value, so you catch an error
        console.error(err);

        return "catch";
    } finally {
        // but this return statement takes priority over catch
        return "finally";
    }
}

const result = example(";");
console.log(result);
```